# How to Read video from a tcp port number C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, port

I am trying to read a video stream from a port number but the application seems to freeze at `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);`.

C#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    msg("Client Started");
    clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 65200);
    label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
}  

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
    msg(returndata);
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: If it freezes at `NetworkStream.Read()`, it means no data has arrived yet. PS. `NetworkStream.Read()` returns the number of bytes _actually read_, you can't assume it reads exactly what you want in a single go.

Comment: OK Thanks. Do you know how I can test/see what is on the port ? using an existing tool? Because I downloaded a software which previews video on that port over TCP and I would like to access it.

Comment: I guess the most popular network analyzer is Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Intercept the protocol being used and implement that. No video protocols I know of start spewing out video to any connected socket, at least there'll be some form of handshake.

Comment: What do you mean by intercepting the protocol is my approach wrong?